# use effect doesn't return both functions

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `useEffect` to get values from two functions inside it and I can get only the values from one function why?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  loadCategories();
  ownerBranches();
}, []);

const loadCategories = () => {
  getCategories().then((c) => setValues({ ...values, categories: c.data }));
};

const ownerBranches = () =>
  getMyBranches(user.token).then((b) => {
    setValues({ ...values, branches: b.data.branches });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have two async calls, I think the problem is using `values` directly from the state. You should set the state with the callback as follow:

```
const loadCategories = () => {
  getCategories().then((c) => setValues(prevValues => ({ ...prevValues, categories: c.data })));
};

const ownerBranches = () =>
  getMyBranches(user.token).then((b) => {
    setValues(prevValues => ({ ...prevValues, branches: b.data.branches }));
  });
```

Also, since you have two different things inside the same object, you might consider having two different variables with state instead of an object with both, that's why hooks are awesome :)

Comment: I'm 90% sure that's the problem because in both calls the `values` have the original value :)